# How to verify if a method in a JavaScript object follows a particular interface?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm relatively new to JS and i have come across this scenario, where i need to identify if a method defined in a JS object follows a particular interface.

Let me explain with the help of an example:

```
let logger1 = {
    log: function(message, meta){
        //logging functionality
    }
};

let logger2 = {
    log: function(level, message, meta){
        //logging functionality
    }
}
```

There are 2 logger objects (logger1 or logger2), which has its own logging functionalities. They can get passed from the client to a library, that the client consumes. 
Library expects the log method to be of a particular interface, which is already mentioned in the library documentation. Inside the library, how would we verify if the logger object passed in has the 'log' method that matches the interface, the library is expecting ?

```
let Library = function(logger){
    //Here I can verify if the 'log' function is defined. But how do i make sure the log 
    //function matches the interface that the library is expecting ?     
    //Let's say the interface that the library is expecting is function(level,message,meta),
    //which is satisfied only by logger2.
    if(logger && typeof(logger.log) === 'function'){
        this.logger = logger;
    }
    else{
        this.logger = console;
    }
}

let lib1 = new Library(logger1);
let lib2 = new Library(logger2);
```

Comment: Hi Boney, JavaScript do not support this because it is a loosely typed programming language, if you really need this, maybe you can user TypeScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot really. A Javascript function can omit parameters that it doesn't use, so the function may have *fewer* parameters and still be compatible. The function may define *more* parameters which will become `undefined` if not passed, and hence still be compatible. It may internally use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) and hence not define any parameters, and still be compatible. It may name any of its parameters any way it wants, and still be compatible, so even inspecting the parameter names won't help you at all.

The only thing you can do it use something like [Typescript](http://typescriptlang.org) and add compile-time checks.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, tricky one.
We would just determine the interface first and then the implementation. In this case we would code logger1 to have the signature: `( message, meta )` and logger2 `( message, meta, level )` .

That way we can call either function with eg. `( 'test', 'extra', 1 )` and logger1 will just ignore the level argument.

If you work with a system that has to juggle alot of different argumented versions, it might be better to just use an object as the only argument every time: `function( config )` and just add extra properties when needed.
That way you can also force the interface to stay the same while also being extendable in some way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property length property for function which gives number of arguments it holds

Example:

```
let logger1 = {
    log: function(message, meta){
        //logging functionality
    }
};
console.log(logger1.log.length); // 2

let logger2 = {
    log: function(level, message, meta){
        //logging functionality
    }
}
console.log(logger2.log.length); // 3
```